# Gradle dependency resolved but marked as unresolved and not available in IDE

Tags: java, gradle, nexus

I can't give a lot of context since it's a private project, but I'll try to do my best.
There's a repo (nexus), it has my artifact. I try to add it to another project as a dependency, of corse I provide a repository field with authentication, the same as I did earlier (with the same repo).

But the dependency is not being resolved in my IDE. I made a scan in gradle, it does resolve the dependency, it finds the repo where it exists, it looks fine. But in the log it's marked as (n) - unresolved for some reason which I can't understand. Nothing in logs (even --debug) points to anything. I see in logs that it successfully finds a repo which has this dependency, it's alright. But it is unavailable in my project.

That dependencies were regularly pushed using maven-publish, they exist in the repo.
Also gradle gives no errors during project loading (nothing like "unresolved dependency error"), as well as it can't build the project since ClassNotFound exceptions.

I tried to create another project, but none of artifacts in that repo are being resolved (but they were fine a while ago). I tried to open the project in another IDE, it has the same problem.

Worth to note that I have another repo on the same nexus and artifacts from there are being resolved successfully. Also I even tried to create a test public repo for a minute, but it still does not download/apply that dependencies.

Any ideas I can check out?

Answer (score 0):

It was very weird. I've messed with it a lot and saw that the file in nexus has a full name (with -all suffix of shadowJar) for some reason! I used it all the time and maven-publish automatically converted the file to projectname+version, excluding all suffixes. I tried to manually change the name and it worked!